# TAB not working when changing CTRL+S to save file in vim

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I tried to save a file in vim by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. I came across this link http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_Ctrl-S_to_save_current_or_new_files and according to it added these pieces of codes in .basrc and vimrc respectively:

```
vim()
{
local STTYOPTS="$(stty --save)"
stty stop '' -ixoff
command vim "$@"
stty "$STTYOPTS"
}
```

and

```
nmap <C-s> :wq!<cr>
```

Ok now <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> saves the file. But <kbd>TAB</kbd> doesn't work now in insert mode. When I press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, cursor returns to first column of current line!! Any solutions?

Comment: Don’t do `nmap`, use `nnoremap`. [Explanation](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Comment: And learn to use the proper shortcuts and mappings. `:w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:nmap` only defines the mapping in normal mode. For insert mode, use `:imap` (in general, prefer `:inoremap` unless you really need remapping to take place), and first leave insert mode by prepending `<C-o>` (for a single command) or `<Esc>` (more appropriate here, since you want to leave the buffer with `:quit`, anyway).

```
:inoremap <C-s> <C-o>:wq!<cr>
```

---

BTW, I find it interesting that you also want to quit the buffer. For me, the mapping is helpful because I can quickly type it in the middle of editing, so that I can frequently persist the changes.

```
" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode
:nnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>
:vnoremap <C-S>     :<C-U>update<CR>gv
:cnoremap <C-S>     <C-C>:update<CR>
:inoremap <C-S>     <C-O>:update<CR>
```

Comment: do I add your second block of code to my _gvimrc file or do I just need to run each command and then vim is set with these new mappings?

Comment: @whytheq You put those into your `_vimrc` file to make them permanent. `_gvimrc` should be reserved for GUI-only customizations; it doesn't matter here, but you cannot use it e.g. to customize plugins.

Comment: I'm using gvim - if I add the second block of script to _vimrc will it mean that CTRL+S will save the buffer when I have it open in the GUI?

Comment: +1 ok - seems to have worked - your block has 4 lines so I assume it means I can use `CTRL+S` in 4 different vim situations? normal (n) mode, insert (i) mode ...?

Comment: @whytheq Yes, there's a slightly separate mapping for each _mode_.

Comment: I assume the first line is (n)ormal mode - and the last line is (i)nsert mode but which modes do the middle two lines apply to.

Comment: @whytheq The comments here is the wrong place to learn Vim; please see the help, e.g. `:help map-modes`.