# Is write / Save / :w the same in gVim

Tags: vim

In Gvim I have the following File menu:

[image]

Next to Save it says `:w`.

Recently I've been informed that `:w` is not save but is write.

Why is the menu set out like this and what are the differences between `write` / `Save` / `:w` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Save" is the standard term for "write everything to disk", and that's what plain `:w` does.

However, `:w` also has a number of additional arguments which can make it do other things, such as append part of the current file to some other file (see `:h :w`). Hence, it is more accurate to call `:w` a write command, rather than just a save command - but plain `:w` is equivalent to a simple save command.

Comment: +1 thanks for help on this. This term _buffer_ is used quite a bit when talking about Vim - _buffer_  isn't a term I've used much before?(japanese - probably more challenging than Vim)

Comment: @whytheq: Basically, a buffer is a file loaded into memory. Try reading `:h window`, that should give you an idea about the basic terms used in this context.

Comment: ...ah - so this term is a generic comp science term rather than a vim term?

Comment: @whytheq: Yes, but in computer science, it usually refers to some temporary storage of input or output (e.g. the next 15 seconds of a NND or YouTube video you're watching). I don't really think of that kind of buffer when I think of a Vim buffer; so I'd say they're slightly different - but I guess that partially depends on your point of view.

Answer (score 4):

The `:w[rite]` command is very versatile, it can do a lot of things. But in its plain, short `:w` form without arguments, it persists the current buffer contents to disk, i.e. does what is usually associated with `File > Save`.

Note that there's also the `:update` variant, which only performs the write when the buffer has been modified. Many users bind this command to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> shortcut, to allow quick and frequent saving.

Comment: +1 thanks for extra info - is it easy to bind commands to shortcut in Vim?

Comment: @whytheq See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14088849/813602) for how to map Ctrl-S, and `:help mapping` for the general help.

Comment: ok thanks you - I commented on your other answer - you really like vim? which languages do you edit using vim? (I'm a 2-day old user of vim and still wondering about the point. I've started playing with Python and will start some Java this summer)

Comment: @whytheq I edit all sorts of files in Vim (and write my mails and Stack Overflow answers in it), but be aware that **Vim is not an IDE**, just a very powerful text editor.

Comment: +1 for informative answer. just a small note for linux terminal user. If you got surprise by pressing `ctrl-s`, press `ctrl-q` to get control back. :D  btw, @whytheq I think your question got answered by at least one of the current 4 candidates. don't forget upvoting and accepting. :) And, vim is right way to go, keep going...

Comment: @Kent I'd already up-voted everyone excl Fabian (sorry) before you wrote your comment. I mark answers as correct usually quite a long time after asking questions but I always mark someone as correct. You say vim is the way to go but Ingo says it is not an IDE....so what won't I use vim for in the future that is part of another IDE?

Comment: @IngoKarkat you say it is just "a very powerful text editor" - but I can't do this [**another vim post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385589/how-do-i-execute-a-python-script-using-vim) with a text editor like notepad or Word ....surely it is not just a _text editor_

Comment: @whytheq Okay, so it's a text editor heavily geared towards programmers and IT professionals :-)

Comment: @IngoKarkat ...for me it is currently a very complicated text editor that I have problems even typing my name into! For you it sounds like the centre of your development tools...so I'd say for some a complicated text editor and for others a very powerful development tool

Answer (score 3):

It's basically writing the buffer to the current file (using vim myfile.txt).
And you can also save this buffer as a new file using (:sav mynewfile.txt)

Comment: is the term _buffer_ a generic computer science term or something specific to vim?

Comment: Buffer is a generic term (e.g. intermediate storage in memory before writing physically data to a disk).

Answer (score 1):

GVim is an attempt to make Vim more accessible to users unfamiliar with the command line and those menus are there to ease the pain you may feel when faced with an editor without traditional menus.

Those menu labels, "Save", "Open", "Exit"… use a familiar naming scheme for your convenience but Vim, like its ancestor Vi, doesn't really adhere to the WIMP convention: Vim's commands have different names and may work differently from the norm. The commands on the right of each menu item are there as hints: the idea is that you learn them and, progressively, stop using those menus and use the command line exclusively as it's far more efficient.

Also, Vim has an extensive built-in documentation. Use `:help :command` if you want to know what `:command` does, `:h :w` for example.